# socket in service slow down when press home

Tags: android, sockets

I'm developing a voice communication app. In my app, there are 6 threads(
1. receive data from PC through a TCP socket;
2. decode received data using jni;
3. play decoded data using AudioTrack;
4. record pcm data using AudioRecord;
5. encode pcm data using jni;
6. send encoded data through another TCP socket
) running in a service.
it runs well in the main activity. However, the problem is, when press home, the two socket slow down in their work. they can not receive/send data as quikly as in the activity, which causes voice delay on both sides. when back to the main activity, they work well again.
I have already set their thread priority by using
`android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);`
but it does not work at all.
could anyone give me some advise?

Comment: Whatever else is going on, 6 threads seems quite excessive for this problem, suggesting the design might be suboptimal.  Are any of them busy waiting?  What is the cpu utilization per thread, from ddms or from the adb shell ps with the threads flag?

Comment: Yes, the CPU is high to 95%, maybe this is the main factor, I'll check my program. Thank you for giving me these tips!